# Laravel 4 - Mcrypt extension required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just finished installing Ubuntu, setting up Apache, MySQL, and PHP. I then decided to install the Laravel framework. I ran a `composer install` and got the following error:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required. Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

I then installed mcrypt deal and all that remained was the artisan error. I decided to go on about my business because I couldn't find a solution online.

Now I am starting my first laravel project. I ran `php artisan migrate:install` and it says `Mcrypt PHP extension required.`

What can I do to fix this?

I ran this command and it didn't help:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

I've ran this a couple of times and it just says its installed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: `php -v` tells me I am running 5.5.9

Comment: Instead of `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`, try `sudo apt-get install php55-mcrypt`. Let me know if its works

Comment: Does `php -m | grep mcrypt` give you anything?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen No, it does not.

Comment: On my Ubuntu box, the available extensions are in `/etc/php5/mods-available`, not `/etc/php5/conf.d`.

Comment: @Phil that command just shows so much stuff I wouldn't know where to look. I know in my .ini file all the mcrypt stuff is commented. I wouldn't know what to put in, though.

Comment: @Phil you're right. mine is the same. That `20-mcrypt.ini` file is a broken link now. How can I overwrite it?

Comment: SverriM's suggestion (`php -m`) was better anyway. You shouldn't need to edit any `.ini` files. It's usually just a simple matter of creating a symbolic link to the appropriate extension file. Are you absolutely sure your symlink `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini` is valid

Comment: @Phil check out my comment above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the extension config file has been linked into the correct spot. This is accomplished via the `php5enmod` utility. You shouldn't be creating symbolic links directly

I'd say this should work. First, remove the symlink you created...

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

then use the `php5enmod` tool

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

then reload Apache

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```