# Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php

I installed laravel via composer, but when running the site its giving an error of

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I installed php5-mcrypt also, but still the error persist.

Comment: Try restarting your server

Comment: call `phpinfo.php` and check is `Mcrypt support enabled` ?

Comment: did all that but not working, restarted, checked Mcrypt is not there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mcrypt is installed but not enabled use

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that wheather the configuration files has been linked properly.It can be done via `php5enmod`.

Remove the symlink created by

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Then  `use the php5enmod tool`

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Finally reload apache

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Check the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599569/laravel-4-mcrypt-extension-required)